# Intent filter not working with annotations

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

i'm using andorid annotations library in my project.I'm stuck with one little problem .
When a user login using his credential, MainActivity.class will be opened. And token will be saved in database. Next time user will open the app, it checks (in SplashScreen) whether the user previously logged in or not. If he did logged in, MainActivity will be opened & i'm using intent filter to clear the stack/task.

```
if (!id.equalsIgnoreCase("default")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity_.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity_.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Everything is working fine except intent filters. In MainActivity.class when i press the Back Button, the SplashActivity opens and app is not minimizing. It feels like that the stack is not cleared. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just finish the splash activity while starting `MainActivity.class/LoginActivity_.class` from `SplashActivity.java`

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks alot. @Santanu

Comment: feel free to update the answer if it worked @QalbHussain